# Listen to user inactivity with AWS Amplify / Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Given that you can set access, refresh and ID token expiration time through the Amazon Cognito Console. How can I listen for the token expiring, so that I can redirect the user back to the login page and show an informational message when that happens?

I noticed that Amplify has a Hub utility where you can add listeners, but I'm not sure what to listen for.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/hub/q/platform/js/#state-management

Comment: If you are using amplify in your front end it will automatically use the refresh token to generate fresh tokens when they expire.

Comment: It will only refresh if the user is active, it's connected to the API calls a user makes etc. If the user is inactive, the token will not refresh. I want to implement a logout if that happens.

Comment: Just check the expiration of the refresh token when your app loads. "so I can log the user out of my web app": sounds like your approach is a bit backward. Tokens expiring is by its very nature "signing out" when it comes to stateless auth.

Comment: I will rephrase the question. I simply want to redirect the user to the login page when the token expires due to inactivity, what is backwards with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did quite a bit of resarch and found out that using the `Amplify` util called `Hub`, you can listen to the refresh token expiring, as well as other authentication related events.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/hub/q/platform/js/

Here's an example of a hook making use of it, React style:

```js
export const useCognitoContextProvider = () => {
  const [context, setContext] = useState({ isSignedIn: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    const authListener = ({ channel, payload: { event } }) => {
      if (channel === 'auth') {
        switch (event) {
          case 'signIn':
            setContext(prevState => (prevState.isSignedIn ? prevState : { ...prevState, isSignedIn: true }));
            break;
          case 'tokenRefresh_failure':
            SignOutService.signOut();
            break;
        }
      }
    };

    Hub.listen('auth', authListener);

    return (): void => {
      Hub.remove('auth', authListener);
    };
  }, []);

  return context;
};
```

And usage:

```js
// CognitoContext.js

export const CognitoContext = createContext({ isSignedIn: false });

// App.js

const cognitoContext = useCognitoContextProvider();

<Provider store={store}>
  <CognitoContext.Provider value={cognitoContext}>
    <Routes />
  </CognitoContext.Provider>
 </Provider>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `return (): void ...` I know that is to cancel the listener, but I don't understand the lifecycle of the return () in the UseEffect. Will it run after Hub gets just 1 event?

Comment: It's a clean up function that will be run when the component unmounts. More info here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup